# The payload for iOS is around 2 kb, but I'm not getting some of my push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm pretty sure I'm not getting this payload because it is too large, but I feel like it should be reasonable.

**Payload**:

```
{ 
alert: "STRING WITH 90~120 CHARACTERS",
badge: 5,
sound: "default",
other: { notification_type: "post_created", 
         post_id: "f9602bb0-9c04-4c65-a636-2c2465e866db", 
         other_var: "A 50 CHARACTER LONG STRONG" }
}
```

So, the `alert` and `other_var` are not the strings above, but are what they're described as, 90 characters, and the other 50 characters.

This seems like what would be the maximum data I would send to a phone, but it isn't reaching the device. I am guessing that is too much data, but I was under the impression that iOS now allows 2KB.

Does that also include a 2 KB limit on the sandbox, or is the sandbox still tied down to 256 bytes?

Comment: Is that the exact JSON you are attempting to send? Where's the `aps` dictionary?

Comment: Oh, whoops, sorry. Yeah, that is there... Forgot the library I used does that for me.

Comment: Does is work for shorter payloads?

Comment: Yep, it works for shorter payloads. I've basically confirmed that it is because of memory... I just personally don't feel like that is 2 KB.

Comment: check this link.It might resolve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/9183146/5362916 ..

Comment: Sadly no. I might need to push my app AdHoc to test the production APNS because maybe it is a sandbox thing.