# GCM based chrome notifications text message cutting off

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

While sending chrome gcm notification. in some device my text cutting off some characters in title tag. is there any limit from chrome or gcm? how can i show case full text message in title. i am using sample code of GCM chrome notification.

Comment: Heya this has been answered in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487223/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-that-can-be-displayed-in-android-push-n).

Comment: @noogui, that thread is for Android push notification that support payload delivery but my question is for chrome based notification of GCM here message text displayed from external API. so My question is different from suggested thread.