# Is there a maximum number of characters that Android Notification can have?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there a maximum number of characters that Android Notification can have before it ellipse?

I can't seem to see if there is in the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: https://gravitec.net/blog/push-notification-character-limit-for-ios-android-and-web/#:~:text=A%20basic%20notification%20includes%20a,generally%20limited%20to%20240%20characters. maybe it will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum number of characters that can be displayed in Android and iOS push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487223/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-that-can-be-displayed-in-android-and-io)