# is it possible to send push notification with video/audio IOS?

Tags: ios, audio, video, push-notification

I am working on an application which uses apple push-notification. I implemented this feature and working fine, now client is asking about  sending push-notification with Audio/video file.

Can you please tell me whether apple allows this type of notifications, if YES any suggestion to implement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well yes and no is the answer. You can't really include the audio/video in the push notification.

What you could do is, in the payload of the push notification, add an URL to an audio/video file. Once your user select to view the push notification you can pick up the URL and load the audio/video.

Comment: I'm unable to receive audio notifications. 
Images, gifs and videos are working.
Using FCM

Comment: @iOS_Developer open a new question with a working example. Nobody will be able to help you without more information.  Also you should not post question in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this and found this thread. I would like to update it by saying that with iOs 10+ now images, video and audio are now supported with little limitations which are:

Devices WITH force touch support video, images and audio.

Devices WITHOUT force touch only support images.
(not sure if audio is supported too, but videos definitely are not supported)

take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationattachment

Answer (score 0):

push notification is simply a message, and it has a very limited length (256 characters, including service, or [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text)). It can add a number on the icon, or play sound by it name (sound should be in the folder of application) and actually show a message. You can pass additional data - number, link or resourceId, but the resources need to pass in other ways