# Push messages longer than 255 characters not reaching iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send a push notification to a device - which is longer than 255 characters.

I'm not getting any errors from Apple servers but the push notification does not reach my device.

1. Using Pusher (https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) the push notification DOES reach the device - using the same certificate.
2. Sending a push notification smaller than 255 characters DOES reach the device

What could be the issue?

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text

Answer (score 0):

Usually, push notifications that are too long, such as over 255 characters as you have mentioned do not make it into the user's device due to the fact that IOS might believe that these notifications are spam notifications. This also forces the developer to be as concise as possible, so the user can get the full information they need from just a quick glance at the screen of their device.
Also, take a look at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text?lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation from Apple Push Notification Service:

> Each remote notification includes a payload. The payload contains
>   information about how the system should alert the user as well as any
>   custom data you provide. In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed
>   for a notification payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification
>   service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to
>   iOS 8 and in OS X, the maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)