# Actual Android push message character limit?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I thought it was a [4KB payload limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) from the official documentation and I sent messages with over 1000 characters but they were truncated to 300-400 because the notification drawer would only display 11 lines. What's the actual, official limit? What's the highest number of characters I know I'm going to get displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging allows you to **send** message payloads up to 4K. But that doesn't mean the receiving device can **display** a message of that size.

For iOS I found this question on maximum display for various notification display types: [What is the maximum length of a Push Notification alert text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text)

Urban airship also has a great [table that shows the maximum number of characters for both iPhones and some common Android phones](https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/articles/213491643-What-are-the-Maximum-Characters-for-Push-Notifications-).

From those sources it seems that:

- The maximum number of characters displayed depends on iOS version, notification display style, and device type/size.
- Your experience of 300-400 characters is in the common range for the notification drawer on Android and much higher than for the notification center on iPhones.