# Notification length on Android emulator: Pixel 3a

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to send push notifications to devices that come from a different backend so are not at all managed by the app or Android Studio.

I've been testing it with an Android Studio emulator and a flutter app. Anyway, when I get the message on the emulator it's not shown completely, meanwhile, with a real device I can see it entirely.

Is that an emulator problem, or a device one?

I'm using `Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64`.

Are there some settings that I can change in the SDK Manager or in Virtual Device Manager?

Comment: how long exactly is your message? in terms of number of characters.

Comment: that's an undefined but with a real device the same characters number is shown. For this example i used around 300 chars that seems to be, according to theese https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870080/actual-android-push-message-character-limit and  https://support.airship.com/hc/en-us/articles/213491643-What-are-the-Maximum-Characters-for-Push-Notifications- in range