# Maximum character count for local notification body - React Native iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, push-notification

I have implemented Local Notification in my React Native App.

Package using [react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios](https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios)

I have tried to fire local notification and it's a success. But local notification does not show all the Text of the body. Any maximum length or any solution for showing full text ?

My code :

```
  showNotification = (id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}, channel) => {
    console.log('SHOWWWWWW');
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      /* Android Only Properties */
      ...this.buildAndroidNotification(
        id,
        title,
        message,
        data,
        options,
        channel,
      ),
      /* iOS and Android properties */
      ...this.buildIOSNotification(id, title, message, data, options),
      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: title || '',
      message: message || '',
      playSound: options.playSound || false,
      soundName: options.soundName || 'default',
      userInteraction: true, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was opened by the user from the notification area or not
    });
  };

  buildIOSNotification = (id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}) => {
    return {
      alertAction: options.alertAction || 'view',
      alertBody: message || '',
      category: options.category || '',
      userInfo: {
        id: id,
        item: data,
      },
    };
  };
```

[image]

**UPDATED SOLUTION :**

Maximum character length is 256 on iOS Side

Comment: This is the “preview” of the notification. It should be short! If you have a longer message to deliver, this is not the place.

Comment: @matt the thing this it only shows 256 characters.. I think apple has limit the length.. Any solution

Comment: ascandroli has answered your question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text)

Answer (score 0):

ascandroli has answered your question here: [What is the maximum length of a Push Notification alert text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text)